# Обход ограничения загрузки файла

Tags: php, upload

Есть ли в php или другом языке возможность обхода ограничения размера загружаемого файла? Решение мне представляется таким образом: загружаемый файл бьется на части, заливается по частям, а потом склеивается. Но как это реализовать (если это вообще возможно)?

Comment: На PHP это кажется малореальным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решения на php нет (если только серверные расширения какие ставить). PHP стартует после обработки входящего запроса.

Могу предложить копнуть в сторону флэш-загрузчиков - он может загрузить файл "в себя" и дальше режьте как хотите на части. Ну а алгоритм элементарный - передавать что-то типа

```
upload.php?file=myfile.avi&part=15&hash=m342lkwkjfp
```

а в POST кусок файла, если кусок меньше буфера - можно собирать.

[Это даже уже используется.](http://www.aurigma.com/docs/iuf/sending-file-in-single-request-or-in-several-chunks.htm)

[И даже вот сам загрузчик =)](http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, большие файлы вовсе не обязательно передавать на бэкэнд, с этой задачей справится и фронтэнд. 
А во-вторых, полностью избавится от ограничения все равно не удастся. В любом случае, как минимум, останется ограничение файловой системы на максимальный размер файла.

В случае использования в качестве фронтэнда nginx, я бы предложил установить [upload модуль](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html) и выставить [ограничение на размер тела запроса](http://sysoev.ru/nginx/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size), столько сколько вам необходимо, вплоть до максимума ФС. 
Тогда задачу на загрузку файла полностью возьмет на себя nginx (по сути он просто, сохранит тело запроса во временном файле), а на бэкэнд придет просто ссылка на закаченный файл.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, в htaccess добавьте такие строки...

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```